# zend lucene close to start of field

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, indexing, full-text-search

i use zend lucene for search.
I form my index with that code

```
$doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
            $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('word_id', $word['id']));

            $boostField = Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('priority', $word['priority']);
            $doc->addField($boostField);
            $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::unStored('description', $word['name'], 'UTF-8'));
            $index->addDocument($doc);
```

Parse search string with that code:

```
 $query=  str_replace(array('-','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')'), ' ', $query);
        $query = trim($query);
        $words = explode(" ", $query);
        unset($query);
        $query = "";
        foreach ($words as $word) {
            $query.='(' . $word . '*)';
            if ($word != end($words)) {
                $query.=' AND ';
            }
        }
        return $query;
```

And search with that code:

```
 try {
            Zend_Search_Lucene::setResultSetLimit($limit);
            $index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open($this->_indexPath);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            return $index->find($query, 'score', SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, 'priority', SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
```

So, my problem-i have in index some fields like:black bag for nootebook,blue bag for nootebook, nootebook, nootebook apple.
And for example i input "notebook" and i want "nootebook,nootebook apple" in top results.
But i have bags in top results! What i doing wrong? What i need to do for having results with max close position from start on search field?
It is possible?

Comment: Can you explain what logical distinction should be made between "notebook apple" and "black bag for notebook", as far as relevance to the query "notebook"?

Comment: in "notebook apple" word "notebook" is max close to left side. In "black bag for notebook" word "notebook" is far away from left side. I want make search, what will be based on how close to left side is word.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any `Query` or `Similarity` implementation that handle this case directly.

A [`SpanQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanQuery.html) might be used to accomplish similar behavior, except that there is no capability to match the beginning of the query.  The workaround that occurs to me, is to add a keyword to the begining of the field you want to search in this way, and search a Span with that keyword.  So, if I index:

```
xxxbeginxxx notebook apple
```

You could search with a [SpanNearQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanNearQuery.html) like:

```
SpanNearQuery spanNear1 = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] {
new SpanTermQuery(new Term("description", "xxxbeginxxx")),
new SpanTermQuery(new Term("description", "notebook"))},
10, true);
```

Kind of a hacky solution.  You'dd have to handle making sure that term was always added at index time, and removed before display to the user, yourself.

Perhaps someone knows a better way, but I believe that should get you the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: See Zend's [Query Language specification](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.query-language.html).  The query parser creates this sort of query like:  `"xxxbeginxxx notebook"~10`.

Comment: I try to do:  code  $query = "";
        $query.='"'."xxxbeginxxx $words[0]".'"'.'~10 ';
        foreach ($words as $word) {
            if ($word!=$words[0]) {
            $query.='"' . $word . '"';
            }
            if ($word != end($words)) {
                $query.=' AND ';
            }
        }
        return $query; code

I don't know how post code in somments. I try use that "xxxbeginxxx term"~10, but my search lucene just die with exeption and all. And if xxxbeginxxx is something abscract, what i need to write-i don't know what

Comment: As I stated in my answer, `xxxbeginxxx` is not something provided automatically.  You would have to manually add it to each field you wanted to search in this way.  I'm not sure why you would be getting an exception from passing in that query either way though.  Some information about the exception you are getting would help, but it won't work unless you add that term to the index to search on, either way.